# static block inside static inner class

Tags: java

we know that a static block in java is resovled while compliling, not at runtime. Hence again We know that a static inner class is instantiated during the first call to the nested class.
Now suppose the nested class is having a static block. So, in that case can we say that static block inside the nested class will be resolved when the first attempt to access that nested class is made?
Sample code:

```
public class A
{
public static class B
{
  static A a;
 static
 {
   a=new A();
 }

 public static A getA()
{
   return a;
 }
}
}
```

Now  I am accessing as:
    A a= A.b.getInstance();
I hope at that point only static block in B will be executed and not before that.

Comment: Code please/ With some error messages?

Comment: What do you mean by "resolved"?  It is a block ... not an identifier.

Answer (score 4):

This should answer your question:

```java
public class Test {

    public Test() {
        System.out.println("Test instantiated");
    }

    public static class Inner {

        static {
            System.out.println("Static block executed");
        }

        public Inner() {
            System.out.println("Test.Inner instantiated");
        }

    }

}
```

When calling:

```java
Test test = new Test();
Test.Inner inner = new Test.Inner();
```

We get:

```
Test instantiated
Static block executed
Test.Inner instantiated
```

Answer (score 1):

> static block in java is resovled while compliling

No it isn't.

All static code is resolved once by the classloader, when loaded/initalized.

Comment: That seems like a comment more than an answer.

Comment: @yshavit I don;t image this question will remain around that long

Comment: @yshavit its not just a minor improvement, it fundamentally changes the question.

Comment: @Dgrin91 Yes, it changes the question and then doesn't answer it.

Comment: @yshavit - A Question that is based on a false premise cannot be answered.  Apart from pointing out that the premise is false.

Comment: @StephenC I don't disagree, but that doesn't mean the non-answer should be posted as an answer. Comment, downvote and/or vote-to-close. Isn't that the SO way? Or have we changed to a discussion forum? Anyway, I won't get into a long discussion on it, I've said by part and will now move on. :)

Answer (score 0):

From [jls](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-8.html#jls-8.7) `Compile` time error will happen from `static blocks` only when

```
If a static initializer cannot complete normally.

If a return statement appears anywhere within a static initializer.

If the keyword this or the keyword super or any type variable declared outside the static initializer, appears anywhere within a static initializer.
```

`static block` will be executed when the class is `initialized`, so in your example, the `static block` inside your `static class B` will get executed first.

Comment: I think class is initialized means when classloader loads the class and creates a corresponding Class object for that class.